# Core-Plot dynamic graph don't work

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot, reloaddata

## I need to make dynamic graph with core-plot.

---

So i make button and on touch, popover with tableView where you can select what graph you want to see. So in didSelectRow method i have new array with some points and call `[graph reloadData];`

---

But my graph didn't change. In console i see that array was change but on screen it doesn't.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Does the first graph render correctly and you can't change the data, or does nothing draw? Did the graph query the datasource for the new data?